# Loadrunner and security issues

Tags: security, loadrunner

Accessing an application manually works fine, creating a manual script with web_add_header works fine, but when just hitting record in vugen with the http protocol the webpage gets "page cannot be displayed".
What can cause this? I assume it has something to do with security?
Can I change some settings in vugen to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that this will solve your problem, but I have seen somewhat similar behavior when dealing with security certificates on SSL enable pages. Try installing or re-installing the security certificate for the site in IE before you try recording the script.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your credentials in the system and your browser vendor/version.  Make sure that you have admin rights and that you are using a 32 bit browser (VUGEN is a 32 bit application) is one supported for your version of LoadRunner